# Does hive need exact schema in Hive Export/Import?

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I am using HDP 2.3

- Hadoop version -   **2.7.1**
- Hive version     -    **1.2.1**

I created a table dev101 in hive using

```
create table dev101 (col1 int, col2 char(10));
```

I inserted two records using

```
insert into dev101 values (1, 'value1');
insert into dev101 values (2, 'value2');
```

I exported data to HDFS using

```
export table dev101 to '/tmp/dev101';
```

Then, I created a new table dev102 using

```
create table dev102 (col1 int, col2 String);
```

I imported data from `/tmp/dev10` in `dev102` using

```
import table dev102 from '/tmp/dev101';
```

I got error:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10120]: The existing table is not compatible with the import spec.   Column Schema does not match

Then I created another table `dev103` using

```
create table dev103 (col1 int, col2 char(50));
```

Again imported:

```
import table dev103 from '/tmp/dev101';
```

Same error:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10120]: The existing table is not compatible with the import spec.   Column Schema does not match

Finally, I create table with **exactly same schema**

```
create table dev104 (col1 int, col2 char(10));
```

And imported

```
import table dev104 from '/tmp/dev101';
```

**Imported Successfully.**

Does hive need exact schema in Hive Export/Import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Hive Export, it create **_metadata** and **data** directories where it keeps metadata and data respectively.

On Hive Import, you need new table *(not present in hive)* or blank table with exact same metadata.